# Make <a> tags touch friendly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch

Lets say I have the following anchor in my html page:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Button</a>
```

How can I make it touch friendly? I believe as default it fires the URL on Click - so can I make it to fire the URL on Touch as well?

I have tried to add this function but don't really think it worked.  `$("a").on('touchstart click',  function(e) {};`

I Googled it, but really found nothing surprisingly! Any thoughts? I simply want my anchors to respond quickly. For example I have the following function:

```
//Off-canvas menu
    $("#secondHeader .menu-button").on('touchstart click',  function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#page, #secondHeader").toggleClass("pageOpen");
        $("#headerWrapper").toggleClass("headerOpen");
        $(this).toggleClass("menu-button-active");
    });
```

You can see that I am using `.on('touchstart click'` when I test it from a smart device, it responds quicker than any other anchor on my site, I believe this is because of the "touchstart" command. So can I use that command for my anchors as well?

Comment: Please define *touch friendly*?

Comment: make it Tap friendly? so it responds to a finger tapping on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly would you like to achieve? Most touch-enabled devices map touch (as in: tap) event to click event, so touching anything does the same as clicking them. Simply put, on touch-enabled device tapping the link you have shown would result in navigating to the URL, as intended.

If it is something else you would like to achieve, please give some more details! :)

Comment: That makes my answer valid, according to your question. Click events are by default tap friendly.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this matter. I believed <a> are not touch friendly by default.

Comment: `touchstart` responds to you putting the finger on screen, whereas standard `click` responds to tap (putting a finger and releasing it). `touchstart` is fired also when you put your finger and start dragging the object around, for instance.

Using `touchstart` to fire click events is not a good usability choice, as the event fires _before_ it should - you can accidentally fire the event.